# problems with $\int _0 ^\infty \frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x}(x+1)^2}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm trying to find $\int _0 ^\infty \frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x}(x+1)^2}$ using complex analysis.

My first problem is that I have to deal with the derivative of $\sqrt[3]{x}$ while computing the residue at $-1$. Explain, please, how one can compute the derivative at a point of such functions (with several branches).

And the second problem is that I don't know how to show that the  contour integral over an upper semi circle centred at $0$ has a zero limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\operatorname{Log}(\cdot)$ denote the branch of the complex logarithm such that $\operatorname{Im}(\operatorname{Log}(z)) \in [0,2\pi)$. In particular, the branch cut of $\operatorname{Log}(\cdot)$ is $[0, \infty)$. Then we consider the function

$$ f(z) = \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{3}\operatorname{Log}(z)}}{(z+1)^2}. $$

Note that, if $x > 0$, then

$$ f(x + 0^+i) := \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} f(x + i\epsilon) = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}(x+1)^2} $$

and

$$ f(x - 0^+i) := \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} f(x - i\epsilon) = \frac{e^{-2\pi i/3}}{\sqrt[3]{x}(x+1)^2}. $$

Now, we consider the keyhole contour, where the inner radius is $\epsilon < 1$ and the outer radius is $R > 1$.

[image: keyhole contour]

Integrating $f$ along this contour, applying the residue theorem, and letting the width of the "gap" to $0^+$, we have

$$ \int_{\epsilon}^{R} (f(x + 0^+i) - f(x - 0^+i)) \, \mathrm{d}x - \int_{\lvert z \rvert = \epsilon} f(z) \, \mathrm{d}z + \int_{\lvert z \rvert = R} f(z) \, \mathrm{d}z
= 2\pi i \, \mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z=-1} \, f(z). $$

Now we make several observations:

- If $\lvert z \rvert = r \neq 1$, then by the reverse triangle inequality,

  $$ \left| f(z) \right| = \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{3}\operatorname{Re}(\operatorname{Log}(z))}}{\left|z + 1\right|^2} \leq \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{3}\log r}}{\left| r - 1 \right|^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{r}\left| r - 1 \right|^2}. $$

  So it follows that

  $$ \left| \int_{\lvert z \rvert = r} f(z) \, \mathrm{d}z \right| \leq \frac{2\pi r}{\sqrt[3]{r}\left| r - 1 \right|^2} = \frac{2\pi r^{2/3}}{\left| r - 1 \right|^2}. $$

  Note that this converges to $0$ either as $r \to 0^+$ or as $r \to \infty$.
- On $\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,\infty)$ and for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, we have

  $$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} e^{\alpha \operatorname{Log}(z)}
  = \frac{\alpha}{z} e^{\alpha\operatorname{Log}(z)}
  = \alpha e^{(\alpha-1)\operatorname{Log}(z)}, $$

  which essentially replicates the well-known formula $(z^{\alpha})' = \alpha z^{\alpha-1}$. In particular, the Taylor series for $g(z) = \exp\bigl(-\frac{1}{3}\operatorname{Log}(z)\bigr)$ about $z=-1$ begins with

  $$ g(z) = 1 - \tfrac{1}{3} e^{-\frac{4}{3}\pi i}(z + 1) + \cdots, $$

  and so, we obtain

  $$ \mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z=-1} \, f(z) = - \frac{1}{3} e^{-\frac{4}{3}\pi i} = \frac{1}{3} e^{-\frac{1}{3}\pi i}. $$

Combining altogether, as $R\to\infty$ and $\epsilon \to 0^+$, we get

$$ \bigl( 1 - e^{-\frac{2}{3}\pi i} \bigr) \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt[3]{x}(x+1)^2}
= \frac{2\pi i}{3} e^{-\frac{1}{3}\pi i}. $$

Rearranging, we get

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt[3]{x}(x+1)^2} = \frac{2\pi i}{3\left( e^{\frac{1}{3}\pi i} - e^{-\frac{1}{3}\pi i} \right)} = \frac{\pi}{3\sin(\pi/3)} = \frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}. $$

Answer (score 1):

If we start off with:
$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}(x+1)^2}dx$$
and make the substitution $u^3=x$ we get:
$$I=3\int_0^\infty\frac{u}{(u^3+1)^2}du$$now we can factorise: $(u^3+1)^2=(u+1)^2(u^2-u+1)^2$ and so:
$$I=3\int_0^\infty\frac{u}{(u+1)^2(u^2-u+1)^2}du$$
now we can use partial fraction decomposition to get:
$$\frac{1}{(u+1)^2(u^2-u+1)^2}=-\frac{1}{9(u+1)}-\frac{1}{9(u+1)^2}+\frac{u-1}{9(u^2-u+1)}+\frac{1}{3(u^2-u+1)^2}$$
we can then break our integral down into multiple others:
$$I_1=\int_0^n\frac{1}{u+1}du=\ln|n+1|$$
$$I_2=\int_0^n\frac{1}{(u+1)^2}du=1-\frac{1}{n+1}$$
$$I_3=\int_0^n\frac{u-1}{u^2-u+1}du=\frac12\int_0^n\frac{2u-1}{u^2-u+1}-\frac{1}{u^2-u+1}du=\frac12\ln|n^2-n+1|-3^{-1/2}\arctan\left(\frac{2\sqrt{3}n-\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2*3^{3/2}}$$
$$I_4=\int_0^n\frac{1}{(u^2-u+1)^2}du=\frac{4\sqrt{3}\left(n^2-n+1\right)\arctan\left(\frac{2\sqrt{3}n-\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)+6n-3}{9(n^2-n+1)}+\frac{2\sqrt{3}\pi+9}{27}$$
now just remember that our original integral, $I$ is the same as:
$$I=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(-\frac13I_1-\frac13I_2+\frac13I_3+I_4\right)$$

The answer should come out as $I=2*3^{-3/2}\pi$

Comment: can you explain in more details how did you got the term $-3^{-1/2}\arctan\left(\frac{2\sqrt{3}n-\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2*3^{3/2}}$ in calculation of $I_3$?

Comment: yeah so when you have a quadratic in the denomiator you start by completing the square and want something of the form $z^2+1$ so that you can make the substitution $z=\tan\theta$